# Dúvida com relação a boas práticas com propriedades virtual

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Tenho um projeto que contém minhas classes que representam minhas entidades no meu BD. Então, como exemplo vai aí:

Na tabela `Endereco`, eu recebo uma `FK` de `Bairro(IdBairro)`. Para representar melhor na minha `POCO`, qual a melhor ou única forma? Eu faço:

```
public virtual ICollection<Bairro> Bairros
```

ou simplesmente

```
public virtual int IdBairro
```

Há um momento em que eu devo usar essa ou aquela abordagem?

Comment: Estamos falando de Entity Framework?

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez sim, nesse caso sim.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O modificador `virtual` serve para informar que esta propriedade pode ser modificada por alguma classe que herde desta classe, então só faz sentido você marcar uma propriedade como `virtual` se você planeja criar alguma classe que herde dela e possa modificar o comportamento da mesma.

Usando como exemplo o Entity Framework, você possivelmente teria algo do gênero:

```
public class Endereco
{
    public int BairroID { get; set; }
    public virtual Bairro Bairro { get; set; }
}
```

Isto ocorre porque o `Entity Framework` precisa criar uma classe em tempo de execução. Esta classe irá sobrescrever a propriedade `Bairro` para que ela realize uma consulta quando for acessada, então teríamos algo do gênero:

```
public class Endereco_0C88CB7B3C2849FC85E80ECB5A1FAD4B : Endereco
{
    private Bairro _bairro;

    public override Bairro Bairro 
    { 
        get
        {
            if (bairro == null || bairro.BairroID != this.BairroID)
                this._bairro = context.Bairros.Find(this.BairroID);                
            return this._bairro;
        }
        set
        {
            this._bairro = value;
            this.BairroID = this._bairro!= default(Bairro) ? this._bairro.BairroID : default(int);
        }
    }
}
```

Note que a implementação acima não é nem próxima da implementação feita pelo Entity Framework, está ai apenas para ilustrar o *Lazy Loading* realizado pelo mesmo.

Agora, quanto à pergunta, o que é melhor, aconselho que siga a recomendação dada pelo ORM/*Framework* que está utilizando.

No caso do *NHibernate*, talvez será interessante ter todas as propriedades `virtual` e não ter a contra-parte para as propriedades de navegação, neste caso você teria apenas a `public virtual Bairro Bairro` e não teria a `public virtual int BairroID`.

Já no Entity Framework, eu diria para marcar como virtual `apenas` as propriedades de navegação, e manter a propriedade de navegação e a sua contra-parte, então você teria tanto `public virtual Bairro Bairro`, como `public int BairroID` (este último sem o `virtual`).